# Where is extraResources in mac?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

I made an application using electron-vue.

https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

And I added some files to extraResources in package.json.

```
"extraResources": [
  "sample1/",
  "sample2.txt"
]
```

When I installed app, I can find out extra resources in win.

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\ApplicationName\resources

It's inside here.

But, in mac, I can't find it.

Where is this directory in mac?